# FF Responsive Design Mode Select Dropdown

Tags: html, firefox, frontend

I'm having trouble opening the select dropdown in the responsive design mode of Firefox (61.0.1 64 bit MacOS, but also on Windows and earlier versions).

Taking the following simple select:

```
<select> 
  <option>Test1</option>
  <option>Test2</option>
  <option>Test3</option>
</select>
```

In chrome's responsive design mode (Device toolbar / Mobile simulator), a tap onto the select opens the dropdown list, but in Firefox's responsive design mode (press crtl+shift+M, with a model selected on top, make sure the hand is highlighted blue == touch simulation enabled), it is not working, the touchevent is emmitted, but the dropdown doesn't open.

I added a console.log to see if the tapEvent is emitted, it is.
[Codepen exemple](https://codepen.io/Lumpenstein/pen/jpEMqa)

```
<select onTouchStart=console.log(this)> 
  <option>Test1</option>
  <option>Test2</option>
  <option>Test3</option>
</select>
```

Then I changed the console.log for an alert and very strangely in FF this opens the dropdownlist, in chrome it 'alerts' the select as expected.
[Codepen exepmle](https://codepen.io/Lumpenstein/pen/XBJKBE)

```
<select onTouchStart=alert(this)> 
  <option>Test1</option>
  <option>Test2</option>
  <option>Test3</option>
</select>
```

Do I miss something or is this a bug in FF's touch simulator ?

P.S.: I just tested if it works in firefox on a real mobile phone, no problem there, seems to be just their simulator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's definitely a problem with Firefox's Responsive mode, specifically with the touch simulator. The reason why it seems working if you use `alert` instead of `console.log`, it's because `alert` actually causes the code to throw an exception here:

https://searchfox.org/mozilla-central/source/devtools/server/actors/emulation/touch-simulator.js#99

since `touch` will be undefined, and therefore the code won't continue, and the dropdown will open.

If it doesn't exist yet, it should be add as bug in bugzilla so that it will be fixed in the coming version of Firefox.

Comment: Hey thanks for looking into it. I already searched in Bugzilla, didn't find anything related, gonna submit the bug after work.